# vue-cli-service cannot find my current Node version

Tags: node.js, vue.js

im trying to build docker image, but there some error

> #13 16.12  ERROR  You are using Node v10.24.1, but vue-cli-service requires Node ^12.0.0 || >= 14.0.0.walismacbook@walisdeMBP hello-world % node --version
> v16.17.0
> #13 16.12         Please upgrade your Node version.

but my current Node version is

> walismacbook@walisdeMBP hello-world % node --version
> v16.17.0

how do i change vue-cli-service node version

Comment: The v16 is in Docker? Otherwise upgrade the image there. If it's on your machine, use nvm.

Comment: @kissu yes its docker, should i upgrade docker first?

Comment: You already have v16 there, so it's matching the `>= 14.0.0` so far. Where do you get your error from?

Comment: @kissu error heppend when i create docker image, using this command "docker build . -t my-app"

Comment: What image do you use for your container?

Comment: @kissu I just created small SPA using Vue, just want to deploy in local docker service,

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what image do you have for your node version.

Comment: oh dude, you wonder im using image for Node?   no , Node i installed with homebrew its not iamge

Comment: You need Node to use NPM (or yarn) to install package in your `package.json`, you need those package installed if you want to run a Vue SPA. Start by bringing a recent node image (v16) into your docker file.

Comment: yea much thanks, i have missed this step